# Googling query from anywhere

Tags: command-line, search, google

At times when I am working on my terminal I run into some errors. To resolve these I have to manually paste the error message to google and search for a solution.

Is it possible to select the message and right click to get a "Google it" option rather than having to manually paste and search?

I am not asking about performing a Google search from the terminal or browsing the web from the terminal. What I want is something more general. I want to be able to select a piece of text and get a "Google selected text" with a right-click (or with a keyboard shortcut). I would prefer the search to take place in a browser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Luckily for you, [tualatrix did a small hack on gnome-terminal](http://blog.ubuntu-tweak.com/2010/11/16/gnome-terminal-with-google-search-support.html) and added support to search on Google upon right clicking a message.

You need to add a [third-party PPA](https://launchpad.net/~tualatrix/+archive/personal) for it to work though. Run these commands in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/personal
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
```

Once updated, close all terminal windows and reopen again. It will work as intended.

[image: gnome-terminal with Google support hack]

Answer (score 6):

Keybind `sh -c 'firefox "https://www.google.com/search?q=$(xclip -o)"'` in **System Settings** -> **Keyboard** -> **Custom**

Or use the following script which let you edit the mouse selection before googling it.

```
#!/bin/bash

# get mouse selection
QUERY=$(xclip -o)

# edit selection
QUERY=$(zenity --entry --entry-text="$QUERY" --text='Google')
[ "$?" != 0 ] && exit 0

# search google in firefox (you can use google-chrome, chromium, opera ..)
firefox "https://www.google.com/search?q=${QUERY}"

exit 0
```

To use this script, copy/paste it in a new text file (gedit ..), and name it whatever you like, eg **google_clip.sh**. Set execute permission, `chmod +x /filepath/google_clip.sh` or right-click in Nautilus then **Properties** -> **Permissions** -> check **Execute**. Then keybind it.

Comment: How do I use this script?

Comment: You bind the script to a key using keyboard shortcuts (dash). It will pick up selected text and load the query in firefox

Answer (score 2):

I had similar requirements and I found [Autokey](https://code.google.com/p/autokey/) to be very helpful in being able to search any selected text by activating a python script (below) everytime I pressed a set of keyboard buttons (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> for example).

```
import webbrowser
base="http://www.google.com/search?q="
phrase=clipboard.get_selection()

#Remove trailing or leading white space and find if there are multiple 
#words. 
phrase=phrase.strip()
singleWord=False
if phrase.find(' ')<0:
    singleWord=True

#Generate search URL. 
if singleWord:
    search_url=base+phrase
if (not singleWord):
    phrase='+'.join(phrase.split())
    search_url=base+phrase

webbrowser.open_new_tab(search_url)
```

A tutorial on how to use Autokey can be found here: [Tutorial](https://saravananthirumuruganathan.wordpress.com/2010/04/14/autokey-linux-utility-for-text-substitution-hotkeys-and-desktop-automation/)