# How to make "Search on Google" available in selected text's context menu in gnome-terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal, search, google

I want to have an option like **Search on Google** available in selected text's context menu in **gnome-terminal**. Something similar to the option which is available in selected text's context menu in google chrome / chromium / firefox browser:

[image: search google]

So, something similar like in the above image, but in gnome-terminal. Is this possible?

Comment: Also relevant: [Googling query from anywhere](http://askubuntu.com/questions/211652/googling-query-from-anywhere/685551)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, there is an option. First download the following deb packages:

- the data package: [gnome-terminal-data_3.6.1_all.deb](https://launchpad.net/~tualatrix/+archive/gnome-terminal/+files/gnome-terminal-data_3.6.1-0ubuntu4.1_all.deb)
- the main package: [gnome-terminal_i386.deb (for 32-bit OS)](https://launchpad.net/~tualatrix/+archive/gnome-terminal/+files/gnome-terminal_3.6.1-0ubuntu4.1_i386.deb) or [gnome-terminal_amd64.deb(for 64-bit OS)](https://launchpad.net/~tualatrix/+archive/gnome-terminal/+files/gnome-terminal_3.6.1-0ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb)

Second, install them using the following commands in your terminal:

```bsh
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/gnome-terminal-data_3.6.1-0ubuntu4.1_all.deb

sudo dpkg -i gnome-terminal_3.6.1-0ubuntu4.1_i386.deb
#or, depending on what you downloaded
sudo dpkg -i gnome-terminal_3.6.1-0ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb
```

And third, restart your terminal.

From now, when you will open your gnome-terminal you can quickly search on Google command line errors, warnings and other things. Highlight the text, right-click on it and choose "Search on Google". It opens the default web browser and go to the google search result page:

[image: search on google from terminal]

Source: [Add Google Search to Gnome Terminal in Ubuntu 13.10](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/10/google-search-gnome-terminal-ubuntu-1310/)

Comment: Does not work anymore on 14.04 !?

Answer (score 10):

Using [Colinker](http://sourceforge.net/projects/colinker/), a customizable context menu for selected text, you can search selected text in any application not just the gnome terminal. On Linux systems, Colinker is designed to be used with `xbindkeys` and `xclip`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Ubuntu 18.04**

1. Enable source code in "Software and Updates"
   [image: Enable source code in "Software and Updates"]
2. Go to terminal
3. Became a superuser

```
sudo -s
```

4. Download and install developer packets to build gnome-terminal

```
apt-get build-dep gnome-terminal
```

5. Download and build sources for current version of gnome-terminal

```
cd /usr/local/src
apt-get -b source gnome-terminal
```

6. go to sources ( change the digits "3.28.2" in future versions )

```
cd gnome-terminal-3.28.2
```

7. Download the patch

```
curl https://ypokhilko.linkpc.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/search_on_google.patch_.gz --output search_on_google.patch.gz
```

8. Unzip and apply the patch

```
gzip -d search_on_google.patch.gz
cat search_on_google.patch | patch -p 1
```

9. Configure

```
./configure
```

10. Build solution again

```
make
```

11. Store old version of the gnome-terminal-server

```
mv /usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server /usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server.old
```

12. Copy new version instead of old

```
cp ./src/gnome-terminal-server /usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server
```

13. Kill old instance of gnome-terminal-server (current instance of gnome-terminal will closed too)

```
killall gnome-terminal-server
```

14. Run gnome-terminal and enjoy

**Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS**

11. Store old version of the gnome-terminal-server

```
mv /usr/libexec/gnome-terminal-server /usr/libexec/gnome-terminal-server.old
```

12. Copy new version instead of old

```
cp ./src/gnome-terminal-server /usr/libexec/gnome-terminal-server
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **:-)** Thank you for posting a correct answer, but could you also [edit] end explain what you're doing so the user understand what they're doing and what the dangers are if gnome terminal gets upgraded in the future?

Comment: Yes, please let us know where this `search on google` plugin comes from, source code link would be great.