# How to enable gnome selected text search?

Tags: gnome

A [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/417620/how-to-make-search-on-google-available-in-selected-texts-context-menu-in-gnom) exists, but the answers are too old and have now become irrelevant.

Is this feature removed?